# Android exception ApiException: -1: Core error

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I get a few crashes of my app in AppGalery Connect. And can't find any information what does it mean.
FYI, I use last versions of HMS libs.

```
com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: -1: Core error
at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.k.doExecute(k.java:60)
at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.k.doExecute(k.java:34)
at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:190)
at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager$1.onCallback(HuaweiApiManager.java:278)
at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$BaseAdapterCallBack.onError(HmsClient.java:134)
at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:196)
at com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:175)
at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$CallbackHandler.send(PendingResultImpl.java:490)
at com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(PendingResultImpl.java:467)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: What HMS Core Services are you using? It seems before building the APK, you did not [configure the obfuscation configuration file](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001050176973) to prevent the HMS Core SDK from being obfuscated. To confirm this issue, please provide the info and then I will check it again. :)